# Compiling js failed, export declaration must be at top level of module

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I've Updated my react native app to the latest version and updated the expo from 45 to 50. When I run the 'npx expo' command, Android bundled successful and then I can see the splash screen and then getting the following error. Please find the screenshot attached
[image]
Can anyone help me with this?

I've Updated the the packages dependencies and updated to the latest version wherever necessary. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you reinstall ```node_modules``` or try run ```npx expo start -c ```

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue. I suggest you review your babel.config.js file as that caused the error for me.

My original babel.config.js was:

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      'babel-preset-expo',
      '@babel/preset-env',
      '@babel/preset-react',
      // '@babel/preset-typescript', // Uncomment if using TypeScript
    ],
    plugins: [
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods", { "loose": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }],
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
};
```

Changing it to the below seemed to have fixed the problem:

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      // Ensure 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' is last
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Seems like the items in brackets need to be listed before the items without brackets. In my example, I changed:
OLD: `presets: ['babel-preset-expo', ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}], '@babel/preset-typescript'],`
NEW: `presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}], 'babel-preset-expo', '@babel/preset-typescript'],`